# 8085;Condition CALL Instruction: if condition fails

Tags: 8085, instruction-set

In call instruction there are 5 machine cycles S,R,R,W,W (S is 6 T-states opcode fetch) and thus 18 T-states 
In first machine cycle, t1-t4 is utilized for fetching the opcode and decoding it and t5-t6 is used for decrementing the Stack pointer to facilitate pushing of higher byte of PC onto stack in 4th machine cycle .
Now in conditional CALL instructions there are also 5 machine cycles S,R,R,W,W 
The T-states are given as 9-18 
So if condition fails only first two machine cycles are executed .
Therefore 2nd machine cycle is used for checking the flags in addition to being used for reading from memory .
My question is that if condition fails , then first two machine cycles are executed , which means that in first machine cycle SP will be decremented by 1  but nothing will be pushed as only half of instruction is executed 
Won't this create incorrect operation of stack ?

Comment: What makes you think that the SP is decremented in the first cycle?

Comment: Why else would it have 6 T-states instead of 4?

Comment: Perhaps to fetch and check the flag? To keep the state machine simple? And even if the decrementer is used, the result does not need to be stored.

Comment: If the flags are checked in first machine cycle itself ....then it knows here only that condition has failed .....why does it execute second machine cycle then ?

Comment: Who knows? Such a person could linger around here, so let's wait. All *we* could do in the meantime is to guess and speculate, and that leads nowhere.